# Is docker able to compile my custom scripts?

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine

Recently, I coded scripts and utilities in linux then I made custom installer which take about 1 hour to complete 100% master code is in Perl then my main perl program compile software as system main framework to use other scripts.

Now, how can I use docker to put installation process in it or how can I use docker to use compiled perl program which relies on lots of scripts.

I was thinking, this may not be possible but if so, how?

Comment: Hi @Haroon Ahmad  - this question is a little broad for SO. We're typically better answering more specific questions. You might want to start with a tutorial like this https://perlmaven.com/getting-started-with-perl-on-docker and come back when you have example code / config for us to look at.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question.